# Multi-part Identifier could not be bound - Update Query SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

SQL Server novice here.

```
UPDATE dbo.ObjectivesApproved  
SET dbo.ObjectivesApproved.VAP = 'Y'
WHERE ((dbo.Approved.Cri_Group In ('X01' ,'X02' ,'X03' ,'X04' ,'X05' ,'X07' ,'X08' ,'X09' ,'X10' ,'X11' ,'X12' ,'X13' ,'X14')))
```

gives the following error

```
The multi-part identifier "dbo.Approved.Cri_Group" could not be bound.
```

What's causing the error?

**Update:** The above query was a result of trial and error. I'm updating an Access Application to SQL server, and having some trouble with the slightly different dialects of SQL

This is my original Query.

```
UPDATE dbo.Approved 
INNER JOIN dbo.ObjectivesApproved ON dbo.Approved.ID = dbo.ObjectivesApproved.ID 
SET dbo.ObjectivesApproved.VAP = 'Y'
WHERE ((dbo.Approved.Cri_Group 
In ('X01' ,'X02' ,'X03' ,'X04' ,'X05' ,'X07' ,'X08' ,'X09' ,'X10' ,'X11' ,'X12' ,'X13' ,'X14')));
```

This gives the error  - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would translate into

```
UPDATE
    OA
SET
    OA.VAP = 'Y'
FROM
    dbo.Approved AS A
    INNER JOIN dbo.ObjectivesApproved OA ON A.ID = OA.ID
WHERE
    A.Cri_Group IN ('X01' ,'X02' ,'X03' ,'X04' ,'X05' ,'X07' ,'X08' ,'X09' ,'X10' ,'X11' ,'X12' ,'X13' ,'X14')
```

Comment: +1, this should fix your problem.  Read up on table aliasing if your confused about why it looks so different.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying that the update also uses the `Approved` table anywhere, instead you just go ahead and use one if its columns.

On another note, your update looks logically flawed too as you'll update the `ObjectivesApproved` records irrespective of what they contain, i.e. there is no relation mentioned between `ObjectivesApproved` and `Approved`.